# How to make sure that the monster is not in the circle?

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, game-physics

I have a sketch 
https://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/KXQaJK?editors=0011

```
 update(){
    if(!this.prey){    
      return;
    }
    let p = this.calcPointInCircle(this.prey.position,this.lake.position,this.lake.radius);
    this.goToPoint(p);
  }
```

The monster must pursue the victim without entering the circle.

Now it moves linearly to the point closest to the fisherman on the circle.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Simple collision detection could achieve this.

Comment: The monster must pursue the goal without entering the circle, but be as close to the victim as possible.

Comment: It can be achieved by some trigonometrics calculation

Comment: is the monster only permitted to move in a straight line, or can it move in e.g. a circular arc?

Comment: It is desirable that he moved rectilinearly, from point to point, but I would gladly see other implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to just move the monster towards the player at a certain speed, but force the monster's position to remain outside the circle.

```
var currentDist = Math.sqrt(monsterX*monsterX+monsterY*monsterY);
var requiredDist = 50;
if (currentDist<requiredDist)
{
    var f = requiredDist/currentDist;
    monsterX *= f;
    monsterY *= f;
}
```

Not entirely correct as the resulting speed would depend on the arc difference to the player on the circle, but it appears kinda natural:

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/5tq8n6d0/) (drag player around with mouse, monster will chase)

Comment: This is a very nice and simple way of solving the problems; however a downside is that it takes infinite time to converge to the desired point

Comment: your monster is a little slow, gets stuck sometimes on the opposite side of the circle, but I liked the implementation

Comment: @meowgoesthedog how do you mean infinite time to converge? Notice that when the player is within the monster's range of movement for a single frame (its speed) it will become that exact same location, not just very close.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Yes, if they're on opposite sides the resulting first few steps are very small. This can be easily overcome in all sorts of ways, I just set up an initial test implementation here to meet the "stay outside circle" constraint.

Comment: @RocketNuts I finded example http://trinixy.ru/51665-utka-i-lisa-igra.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the algo below:

1- calculate the angle of the line formed by the prey and the center of the lake, let's call this angle *alpha* :

Since tangent of alpha is equal to (yPrey - yLake) / (xPrey - xLake),

```
var alpha = arctan((yPrey - yLake) / (xPrey - xLake));
```

2- When alpha is calculated in radians, you can calculate where the line intersect the circle in point of cordinates x and y:

```
var x = lakeRadius * cos(alpha) + xLake;
var y = lakeRadius * sin(alpha) + yLake;
```

Comment: I believe OP has already achieved this result. What he/she needs is a method to navigate *around* the circular barrier in the case that there is no direct path.